# import MySQL dump into Postgres and escape \

Tags: mysql, postgresql, escaping, plpgsql

I received a MYSQL dump and needs to push it into the Postgres table.

Inside this poi_dump.sql dump, there are many rows of insert. The example as below:

```
Insert into table values (1,'hello','\rthis is a beautiful Alan\'s cottage', '\nbyebye')
Insert into table values (1,'hello','\rthis is a big\"Work', '\nbyebye')
```

I am using PSQL command:

```
psql analytics < poi_dump.sql
```

However, the postgres does not recognize all the \ used to escape in a ' ' field.

```
Errors From Postgres:
Query buffer reset (cleared).
invalid command \nOn
invalid command \n
invalid command \'
invalid command \'
invalid command \'
invalid command \n
invalid command \"Without
invalid command \nPort-a-loo
Query buffer reset (cleared).
invalid command \n
```

How can i make postgres to accept those \r ,\n , 's inside a quote field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't recognize backslash in string by default. But this behave can be simply changed:

```
ides_jmmaj_prac=# select 'hello\nworld';
┌──────────────┐
│   ?column?   │
╞══════════════╡
│ hello\nworld │
└──────────────┘
(1 row)

Time: 0,496 ms
ides_jmmaj_prac=# set standard_conforming_strings TO off;
SET
Time: 0,251 ms
ides_jmmaj_prac=# select 'hello\nworld';
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
ŘÁDKA 1: select 'hello\nworld';
                ^
DOPORUČENÍ:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ hello   ↵│
│ world    │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

Time: 0,496 ms
```

Disable warnings by:

```
set escape_string_warning to off;
```

Probably `\r` should be removed. PostgreSQL using Unix end of lines - only `\n` (I didn't test it).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

Do the mysqlpdump

then I run

```
cat mysqldumpfile | sed "s/,'/,E'/g" > pgimportfile
```